# Can't use JQ to get items within JSON

Tags: json, bash, key, jq

I have this JSON:

```
{  
  "blocks" : {
    "xrb_1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111117353trpda": {    
        "142A538F36833D1CC78B94E11C766F75818F8B940771335C6C1B8AB880C5BB1D": "6000000000000000000000000000000"    
    },    
    "xrb_3t6k35gi95xu6tergt6p69ck76ogmitsa8mnijtpxm9fkcm736xtoncuohr3": {    
        "4C1FEEF0BEA7F50BE35489A1233FE002B212DEA554B55B1B470D78BD8F210C74": "106370018000000000000000000000000"    
    }  
}
```

I am having trouble using `jq` in `bash` to read out:

```
xrb_1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111117353trpda
xrb_3t6k35gi95xu6tergt6p69ck76ogmitsa8mnijtpxm9fkcm736xtoncuohr3
```

I try to do it on [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/) but not having much luck with it.

I have tried with [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/) to get the results and manage find but not when its nested this way.

Answer (score 1):

This `jq` script might work for you:

```
$ cat file
{
  "blocks": {
    "foo_b": {
      "aaa": "bbb"
    },
    "bar_b": {
      "ccc": "ddd"
    }
  }
}

$ jq -r '.blocks | to_entries[].key' file
foo_b
bar_b
```

Answer (score 1):

`keys_unsorted` gives an array of keys. Whence:

```
jq -r '.blocks | keys_unsorted[]' input.json
xrb_1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111117353trpda
xrb_3t6k35gi95xu6tergt6p69ck76ogmitsa8mnijtpxm9fkcm736xtoncuohr3
```

Comment: Ughh...I didn't even know about `keys_unsorted`. Just proves how little I know about `jq`. Nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON is invalid. It's missing a closing bracket.

```
$ cat input.json
{
  "blocks": {
    "xrb_1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111117353trpda": {
      "142A538F36833D1CC78B94E11C766F75818F8B940771335C6C1B8AB880C5BB1D": "6000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "xrb_3t6k35gi95xu6tergt6p69ck76ogmitsa8mnijtpxm9fkcm736xtoncuohr3": {
      "4C1FEEF0BEA7F50BE35489A1233FE002B212DEA554B55B1B470D78BD8F210C74": "106370018000000000000000000000000"
    }
  }
}
```

If you're open to use something else than `jq`, then I'd suggest the Swiss knife tool [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html).

Dot notation:

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '($json).blocks()'
```

XPath notation:

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '$json/(blocks)()'
```

Both with the output:

```
xrb_1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111117353trpda
xrb_3t6k35gi95xu6tergt6p69ck76ogmitsa8mnijtpxm9fkcm736xtoncuohr3
```